# How to draw a curved arrow in Keynote 09?

Tags: keynote

I don't find how to draw a curved arrow in a Keynote'09 presentation... I'm sure is really before my eyes but .....

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### Create the Arrow

---

1. From the Insert Shape menu choose the "Draw with Pen" tool:
   [image: Step 1]
2. Click once at one end of your curved arrow:
   [image: Step 2]
3. Click **and drag** at the other end of your arrow:
   [image: Step 3]
4. Hit the Escape key to stop drawing.
5. From the line ends menu, choose an arrowhead you like:
   [image: Step 4]

---

---

#### Edit the Arrow

---

To reshape the curve, click on it once, then click on it again;
When the endpoints turn red you can change things:
[image: Step 5]

Click and drag the round circles at the end of the gray Bezier
handles to reshape the curve (a little practice makes perfect):
[image: Step 6]

Click and drag one of the red endpoints to change the start or end:
[image: Step 7]

Comment: Do you know how to reset curve handles on a point? It's very common for me to have a point with handles that cannot be dragged anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should look at this [Thread](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1243007). They speak about Keynote 4, but I think you can do that in Keynote '09 as well.